# NEF file format is not recognize in the image/* accept file

Tags: javascript, html, image, input, photo

I am dealing with exotic imagery file format (RAW of various kind).

so, i have my

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

which work for mostly all format, but for some reason, NEF is not "accepted".

so I have to manually add it after image/*, which looks wrong.

```
<input ... accept="image/*, .nef"/>
```

this is not supported on firefox-linux , nor on opera or chrome-MAC. so i expect it's neither browser or OS dependant

I have read various documentation on the subject, i am not photographer myself, but considering it work with others format.

do you know why the nef format is not supported ?
more important : do you know if others format than NEF is not supported ?

Comment: It's not supported because it's not listed here https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image Nor is Canon CR2, or Minolta MRW or Sony ARW or Adobe DNG. I guess it's because they are raw, unprocessed files not meant for general consumption on the WWW, rather for in-house, personal processing and optimisation. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input element considers the `image/*` to handle image types. Webkit delegates the filter to the OS. For iOS, for instance, `image/*` instructs the dialog to select files belonging to the `UTTypeImage` type.

```
        if ([mimeType caseInsensitiveCompare:@"image/*"] == NSOrderedSame)
            [mediaTypes addObject:UTTypeImage.identifier];
```

This type is equivalent to the `public.image` identifier you can see on [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1).

NEF files belong to the UTI `com.nikon.raw-image` which belongs to `public.camera-raw-image` which belongs to `public.image`.

The problem seems to come from the fact that
this is transmitted to `UIDocumentPickerViewController@initWithDocumentTypes()` which only takes considers UTI declared with `UTExportedTypeDeclarations`.

You can view which type are Imported or Exported using the command

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
```

Here's the result for NEF

```
        uti:           com.nikon.raw-image
        description:   Nikon raw image
        flags:         imported  active  core  apple-internal  
        icon:          
        conforms to:   public.camera-raw-image
        tags:          .nef
```

This leaves us with the following list of images accepted by default when using `image/*` :

- public.radiance : .pic, .hdr
- public.jpeg : .jpeg, .jpg, .jpe, 'JPEG', image/jpeg
- public.jpeg-2000 : .jp2, .jpf, .jpx, .j2k, 'jp2 ', image/jp2
- com.apple.pict: .pict, .pct, .pic, 'PICT', image/pict, image/x-pict, image/x-macpict, "Apple PICT pasteboard type", "NSPICTPboardType"
- com.apple.macpaint-image: .pntg, 'PNTG'
- public.png: .png, 'PNGf', image/png, "Apple PNG pasteboard type"
- public.svg-image: .svg, .svgz, 'svg ', 'svgz', image/svg+xml
- com.apple.quicktime-image: .qtif, .qif, .qti, 'qtif', image/x-quicktime
- com.apple.icns: .icns, 'icns'
- public.xbitmap-image: .xbm, image/x-xbitmap